# Cooking countdown timer with start button

Tags: button, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm creating an app to help the user cook pasta. The user will select a variety of options and the final step will create a timer based on the options they select. (Example: selecting spaghetti noodles, al dente will result in a 10 minute timer) For the purpose of debugging the code, I have removed my code to calculate the cookTime variable and set it equal to 10 (minutes) to make thins a little easier. Here is my code:

```js
<script>
 
    var cookTime = 10;
    
 $("#timerButton").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = Number(cookTime) + ":" + 00;
  startTimer();
 });

 function startTimer() {
   var presentTime = Number(cookTime) + ":" + 00;
   var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
   var m = timeArray[0];
   var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
    if(s===59){
     m=m-1;
    } //if(m<0){alert('timer completed')}

   document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
  m + ":" + s;
   setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
 }

 function checkSecond(sec) {
   if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0){ // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    sec = "0" + sec;
   } 
   if (sec < 0){
    sec = "59";
   }
   return sec;
 }
</script>
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="timer"></div>
  <a href="#" id="timerButton">Start Timer</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your minute and second variables inside your function so they're getting the same values every time.

```
var cookTime = 1;
var presentTime = Number(cookTime) + ":00";
var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
// set your minute and second counters
var min = parseInt(timeArray[0]);
var sec = parseInt(timeArray[1]);

$("#timerButton").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // show initial time (using jquery since you're already using it for your click function)
    $('#timer').html(presentTime);
    startTimer(min, sec);
});

function startTimer(m, s) {
  s--;
  if (s<0) {
    s = 59;
    m--;
  }

  if (m>=0) {
    $('#timer').html(m+':'+pad2(s));

    // pass the current values for m and s into startTimer
    setTimeout(function(){
        startTimer(m,s);
    }, 1000);
  } 
  else alert('time\'s up');
}

// shorter version of your checkSecond function
function pad2(number) {
  return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number; 
}
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j3txcjmz/